# Angular router with nested categories

Tags: angular, routes, nested

I would like to nest categories but without predefine the number of levels
there might be 3-5 levels depending on several factors.

So level 1 would be "categoryX/1", level 2 "categoryX/1/categoryY/2" etc...

Right now we have the routes like this, but it does make things harder down the line so I would really like to have a solution for this.

```
{
path: ':name/:id', component: CategoryPageComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: ':name/:id/:name/:id',
    component: CategorySubPageComponent,
  },
  {
    path: ':name/:id',
    component: CategorySubPageComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '', component: CategorySubPageComponent,
  },
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A little late on this, but... this might work:

```js
  {
    path: ':name/:id', component: CategoriesComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '**/:name/:id',
        component: CategoriesComponent
      }
    ]
  }
```

or something similar. However, this definately works if you don't need to structure it with ids:

```js
  {
    path: 'category', component: CategoriesComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '**',
        component: CategoriesComponent
      }
    ]
  }
```